# How do I update each true key pair in a map in cloud firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I’m working on an app with Flutter.
Each of my users has a map with their to-dos stored in cloud firestore:
[image]

I want to create a future that updates every to-do to false, which is true.
(In my example, that would be ’sport' and ’eat healthy')

---

My Problem:
I don’t really know how to do this. . .

I’d be very grateful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set every field inside the `To-Dos` map to `false` which is `true`. So I would suggest updating every field to `false`. You might think of checking if it  is `true` and then updating it. But for your use case it is not a good option as anyway you want to set every field to `false`. Checking and then updating will only incur extra charges for querying. The following should work for your use case.

```
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

Future<void> updateUserToDos() {
 return users
     .doc('your_document_id')
     .update({
       'To-Dos.Drink Water': false,
       'To-Dos.Sport': false,
       'To-Dos.eat healthy': false
     })
     .then((value) => print("User To-Dos Updated"))
     .catchError((error) => print("Failed to update user: $error"));
}
```

To know more about updating document fields of Firestore in Flutter you can refer to [this document](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#updating-documents).

**EDIT**

So you don’t know which fields are there inside the `To-Dos` map and you need to update every field inside the `To-Dos` map to be false. For that you can iterate over the keys of the map and update a new Map having keys same as that of the existing map and values to be false, then update the `To-Dos` Map field with the updated new Map. You can use the following piece of code. It will update every document inside the `users` collection.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
       .collection('users')
       .get()
       .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
     querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
       var updateMap = new Map();
       var toDos = doc['To-Dos'];
       for (var item in toDos.keys) {
         updateMap[item] = false;
       }
       doc.reference.update({"To-Dos":updateMap });
     });
});
```

To update the `To-Dos` map in any specific document you can do the following -

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
       .collection('users')
       .doc("your_document_id")
       .get()
       .then((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
     var updateMap = new Map();
     var toDos = doc['To-Dos'];
     for (var item in toDos.keys) {
       updateMap[item] = false;
     }
     doc.reference.update({"To-Dos": updateMap});
   });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that I don’t know which To-Dos the user has saved. This varies from user to user.

Comment: Do you have a solution to the problem?

Comment: @Lars I have updated the answer based on your comment. Have a look at the **EDIT** section of the answer.

Comment: It worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic solution here. With your current data model, the only approach is to:

1. Read all documents
2. Change any `false` todo's to `true
3. Write back the document if you made any changes

The only way to make this cheaper (both in monetary cost as in the time it'll take) is to change #1 to only read documents that have a `false` value. In your current model that is only possible if `To-Dos` is an array, and then only for up to 10 values in there with an [`array-contains-any` filter](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array-contains-any):

```
collectionRef.where("To-Dos", arrayContainsAny: [{
  "Drink Water": false,
  "Sport": false,
  "eat healthy": false
}]
```

If the keys in this field are entered by the user, the above may become unfeasible because you can only have up to 10 values in there. The solution in that case would be to change your data model to fit your needs (as is quite common when working with NoSQL databases). For example, you could store a simple top-level `hasUncompletedTasks` field that you update each time you also write the document, and then use that for the query.

Comment: So it’s just not possible to set all the To-Dos in the map to false? The problem is that I can’t display the two maps (hasUncompletedTasks, hasCompletedTasks) together in a stream. In addition, I didn’t quite understand how to change my structure in cloud firestore. Can you help me out again?

Comment: I already explained one possible change in my answer: adding a `hasUncompletedTasks` field to each `To-Dos` document to indicate if any tasks need updating. But even then you will need to read-then-write all those documents, as Firestore doesn't support update queries, where you send a query and a set of update instructions to the database.